# Ipython NameError caused by forgetting module in function

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, nameerror

So within Ipython when ever I do:

```
import os
c = lambda x: os.system(x)
c('clear')
```

I get:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2e6d485a2a4e> in <module>()
----> 1 c('clear')

<ipython-input-2-edd0d73bfd77> in <lambda>(x)
      2 from importlib import reload
      3 import os
----> 4 c = lambda x: os.system(x)

NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Out of function it works fine:

```
In [1]: import os
In [2]: os.system('clear')
Out[2]: 0
```

In normal python3 and python2 the behavior is as expected.
Any ideas as to what could be causing the peculiar problem?

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: I tried it in IPython 6.2.1 and I don't get any errors.